# Will Merge Into table_x always invalidate package or SP when adding new column to table_x?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I'm trying to understand why MERGE INTO table_x statement(Oracle 12c) will invalidate my package or stored procedure when altering table_x and adding a new column. Am I doing something wrong? I did not expect invalidation to happen.

For example, here is table_x:

```
CREATE TABLE table_x 
( 
       ID number
       ,column_1 VARCHAR2(50)
)
```

We have the following SPs with different ways of writing MERGE INTO clause :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pr_test1 IS
BEGIN
   MERGE INTO table_x x
   USING .... /*the rest of the clauses are the same in both SP, only Merge into is different*/
   ON ....
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN ...
   WHEN MATCHED THEN ...;

END pr_test1;
```

AND

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pr_test2 IS
BEGIN
   MERGE INTO (SELECT id
                 FROM table_x) x
   USING ....
   ON ....
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN ...
   WHEN MATCHED THEN ...;
END pr_test2;
```

On adding a column to table_x:

```
alter table table_x add column_2 varchar2(100);
```

I get

```
select object_name, status from dba_objects;

pr_test1 INVALID
pr_test2 VALID
```

I didn't expect invalidation to occur in either one of the cases. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please expand your `when not matched` clause. My guess is that you're just doing `insert values (val1, val2, ...)` instead of listing the columns to be inserted into to, e.g. `insert (col1, col2, ...) values (val1, val2, ...)`

Answer (score 2):

It is not `MERGE` that invalidated the procedure, but `ALTER TABLE`. That's how it goes; so, recompile the package.

Comment: Agreed the question is written backwards. However the OP may have an interesting point about non-obvious techniques for avoiding invalidation.